# Unable to use I18n.t call in an initializer file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, initializer

I would like to use I18n.t call in an initializer file.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Rails returns the usual "translation missing:" message. 
It seems that the I18n files haven't been loaded yet when the call is made.

Are there any workarounds ?

Thanks

Comment: This has appeared again in Rails 3.1.1 (maybe sooner?).  I would like to usilize the same format for I18n.locale(some_time, :format => :my_format) and some_time.utc.to_s(:my_format).  When I to use the following in config/initializers/time_formats.rb:

    `Time::DATE_FORMATS[:dxl] = I18n.translate('time.formats.dxl')`

I get:

    > Time.now.utc.to_s(:dxl)
    => "translation missing: en.time.formats.dxl"

Comment: Formatting is rather limited.  Since this is so old (and for a previous version of Rails), I created a new Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010092/unable-to-use-i18n-t-call-in-an-initializer-file-in-rails-3-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the problem when I was using Rails 2.3.2.
Since then, I've migrated to 2.3.5 and I18n.t calls work fine in my initializers.