# Unable to use I18n.t call in an initializer file in Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, initialization

I would like to use I18n.t in an initializer file in Rails 3.1.1.

This question already exists for Rails 2 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514536/unable-to-use-i18n-t-call-in-an-initializer-file).  Supposedly, it was answered by a subsequent release.  It appears to be an issue again in Rails 3.1.1.

**The problem:**

I have a custom time format called :dxl.
I would like to format my Email.sent_at datetime as :dxl.

**The solution:**

In can add the format to en.yml (time.formats.dxl) and use it with:

```
I18n.localize(email.sent_at, :format => :dxl)
```

I also want to show the utc time.  I do not see a way to use I18n for this, so I am using:

```
email.sent_at.utc.to_s(:dxl)
```

**The rub:**

To support `to_s(format)`, I believe I need to assign `Time::DATE_FORMATS[:dxl]` in an initializer (e.g. config/initializers/time_formats.rb).

I would rather not duplicate the strftime format string in both en.yml and the initializer.

Unfortunately, it looks like I18n is not usable within an initializer.  When I add this to config/initializers/time_formats.rb:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:dxl] = I18n.translate('time.formats.dxl')
```

I get:

```
> Time.now.utc.to_s(:dxl)
=> "translation missing: en.time.formats.dxl"
```

Is there a way to ensure I18n is ready (has read the en.yml file) in an initializer?

I did verify that the translation does work correctly if I copy/paste the strftime format into the initializer.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you're not just calling I18n.localize(email.sent_at.utc, :format => :dxl) ?

Comment: I believe this how we settled on formatting dates.  This is a little fuzzy for me now, but I do remember that, at the time, we were trying to use .to_s(format) instead of the bulkier I18n.translate.  I also recall that the use of the optional param on to_s caused us some other issues, so we fell back to I18n.translate.